# Decisional boundary SVM caret (R)

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I have built an SVM-RBF model in R using Caret. Is there a way of plotting the decisional boundary?

I know it is possible to do so by using other R packages but unfortunately I’m forced to use the Caret package because this is the only package I found that allows me to calculate the variables importance. 
In alternative, can you suggest a package that allows to plot the decision boundaries AND gives also the vars importance?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Just asking for package recommendations is considered off topic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unlike other methods, SVM does not produce feature importance. In your case, the importance score caret reports is calculated independent of the method itself: https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html#model-independent-metrics

Second, the decision boundary (or hyperplane) you see in most textbook example is based on a toy problem with only two or three features. If you have more than three features, it is not trivial to visualize this hyperplane.